# How can I create a generic class that only works for classes that support certain interface?

Tags: vb.net, generics

```
Class cacheable(Of T As haveTimeStampandMainStringKey)
    Public ReadOnly Property Cache As T
    Public ReadOnly Property timestamp As Date

    Public Shared Function create(cache1 As T) As cacheable(Of T)
        Dim a = New cacheable(Of T)
        a._Cache = cache1
        a._timestamp = Now
        Dim key = T.mainkey 'this things fail to compile
        Return a
    End Function
End Class

Interface haveTimeStampandMainStringKey
    ReadOnly Property TimeStamp As DateTime
    ReadOnly Property mainKey As String
End Interface
```

Basically I want class cacheable to work only with classes that support haveTimeStampandMainStringKey

Yet

`Dim key = T.mainkey` produces an error

Clearly T supports haveTimeStampandMainStringKey interface. So I should be able to access T.mainkey. I can't. Why? What's wrong with the code?

Why?

Comment: What language is this?

Comment: added. It's vb.net. I added the tag

Comment: I would either change `create(cache1 as T)` to `create(cache1 as haveTimeStampandMainStringKey)` or cast cache1 as haveTimeStampandMainStringKey inside the method. That should solve your issue

Comment: It doesn't work because T is a type, not an instance.  You need to have an instance to refer to `mainKey`.  You probably want either `a.Cache.mainKey` or `cache1.mainKey`.

Comment: (If you really want something `Shared` rather than something attached to an instance, you're SOL, it's not supported by .NET, see various lamentations about the absence of "static interfaces" over the years.)

Comment: Oh no. That's so obvious

Comment: @Craig please turn that into an answer

Comment: Done.  (And let he or she who hasn't missed something similarly obvious in the past cast the first stone...)

Comment: @Craig ouch.... someone throw some stone at me :(

Comment: I'm not casting stones, I've made my share of howlers. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because `T` is a type, not an instance.  You need to have an instance to refer to `mainKey`.  You probably want either `a.Cache.mainKey` or `cache1.mainKey`.

(If you really want something `Shared` rather than something attached to an instance, unfortunately, there isn't a good way to do it as it's not supported by .NET except through various reflection-based approaches, see various lamentations about the absence of "static interfaces" over the years.)